# Why doesn't TeX interpolate between root glyphs of different sizes?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, root

I rendered

[image]

using the following code:

```
$ \sqrt{x} \sqrt{y} \sqrt{x^2} \sqrt{\frac{x}{y}} $
```

I find the difference in the gap above the `x` and `y` to be super annoying.  It would be nice if there was greater consistency in the spacing.  It seems like this could be achieved if TeX interpolated between the different glyphs it uses for the root symbol.  I'm curious if anyone knows why it doesn't do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I introdcue `\Csqrt` and `\Cfrac` ("C" for consistent), which just adds a `\mathstrut` into the mix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Csqrt[2][]{\ifx\relax#1\relax\sqrt{\mathstrut#2}\else\sqrt[#1]{\mathstrut#2}\fi}
\newcommand\Cfrac[2]{\frac{\mathstrut#1}{\mathstrut#2}}
\begin{document}

Orig: $ \sqrt{x} \sqrt{y} \sqrt{x^2} $

Rev: $ \Csqrt{x} \Csqrt{y} \Csqrt{x^2} $

Orig: $\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}} \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{y}} \sqrt{\frac{x}{y^2}}$
 $\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}} \sqrt{\frac{y}{x^2}} \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{x}}$

Rev: $\Csqrt{\Cfrac{x}{y}} \Csqrt{\Cfrac{x^2}{y}}  \Csqrt{\Cfrac{x}{y^2}}$
 $\Csqrt{\Cfrac{y}{x}} \Csqrt{\Cfrac{y}{x^2}} \Csqrt{\Cfrac{y^2}{x}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the second revised set, the use of `\Csqrt` is not even required...`\sqrt` is sufficient, as `\Cfrac` picks up the slack.